# Is this sum $\sum_{i+j=4} a_ib_j = a_0b_4 + a_1b_3 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_1 + a_4b_0$ expanded correctly?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this finite sum expanded correctly? Does the order matter?

$$\sum_{i+j=4} a_ib_j = a_0b_4 + a_1b_3 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_1 + a_4b_0$$

Comment: It looks fine, if $i,j \in \mathbb N_0$ :-)

Comment: No, $i$ and $j$ are positive integers :) So $\sum_{i+j=4} a_ib_j =  a_1b_3 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_1$. But you can be more precise, if you want also zero, saying $$\sum_{\substack{i,j\ge 0 \\ i+j=4}}a_ib_j$$ The order does matter, e.g., if $a_i,b_j$ are matrices.